# Prove the sequent $\exists x A(x) \to \forall x B(x) \vdash \forall x (A(x) \to B(x))$

Tags: predicate-logic

I am unable to start the natural deduction process because I don't know how to parse the two different quantifiers on the LHS. A hint would be really helpful

Comment: *Hint*: Assume $A(x)$ and derive $\exists x A(x)$. Using 1st premise derive $\forall x B(x)$ and from it $B(x)$. Then: $A(x) \to B(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that I did understand but I was getting confused with the various scopes of fresh variables

Comment: It is just $(\exists x A(x)) \to (\forall x B(x)) $